# pandas dataframe conditional selecting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I have a Dataframe and im trying to apply some ml algorithms on it.
im using pandas to handle it but im having several problems with it:

1. as you see in the 3rd cell, i have splitted Y into Ytr and Yts. after this the dataframe losses its column names. I've tried to name the column again but it doesn't work.
2. in the 4th cell, Im trying to use conditional statement to create a subset of Y in which Y values are 1(it is named ytr1). but it returns an empty dataframe.

any suggestions on the whole code would be really appreciated since im not really experienced with Pandas

note: if you haven't worked with jupyter notebook, #%% just means a new cell.

```
#%%

from pandas import DataFrame as df
import random 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re 

#%%

# Preparing the DataFrame
labels = pd.read_csv(r'A:\Data Sets\Pima Indian Diabetes\labels.csv', header=None)
ll = labels.loc[:, 0].tolist()

data = pd.read_csv(r'A:\Data Sets\Pima Indian Diabetes\pima-indians-diabetes2.csv', names=ll)
i = data.columns.values.tolist()  # i is the labels of the csv file
i[-1]

#%%

# Spliting the Dataset
X = data.drop(i[-1], axis=1)
Y = data.iloc[:, 8]
Y = Y.to_frame()
Y = pd.DataFrame(Y.values.reshape(-1, 1), columns=i[-1])

tr_idx = data.sample(frac=0.7).index

Xtr = df(X[X.index.isin(tr_idx)])
Xts = df(X[~X.index.isin(tr_idx)])

Ytr = df(Y[X.index.isin(tr_idx)], columns='result')
Yts = df(Y[~X.index.isin(tr_idx)], columns=i[-1])

#%%

# splitting the Classes
ytr1 = Ytr.drop(Ytr[Ytr.iloc[0]!=1].index)
```

X: all the columns except Labels\classes which are 0 or 1 
Y: last column of the csv files that are loaded as labels 
Xtr: fraction of X that Im planning to use for training 
Xts: fraction of X that Im planning to use for testing

Comment: could you show an example of your dataframe and your expected output?

Comment: @ansev dataset is available in this link:

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ktisha/c21e73a1bd1700294ef790c56c8aec1f

Comment: dont provide links, they can change, provide a example of your dataframe

Comment: It has a link downloadzip if you look closer. I dont have access to the files that im importing right now but ive added the last port to provide you a better understanding. the ones that im using is the same dataset without labels. ive uploaded labels as a csv and created a list of labels named "I" @ansev